# Playwright giving "npm ERR! could not determine executable to run" failure

Tags: npm, playwright, npx

Just started playing with Playwright.   Installed and decided to run the tests that come with it.  Can't figure out why it is failing.

```
$ npx playright tests                                                                                                                                            
[11:09:04]
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
FAIL
```

I've double check Typescript installed

```
$ tsc -v   
Version 4.7.4
```

and nom

```
$ npm -v                                                                                                                                                   
8.1.0
```

I looked up solution on this site, and it mentions removing the .git/hooks file - I don't have that.

package.json is straight forward:

```
{
  "name": "project01",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.25.2"
  }
}
```

What on earth am I missing?   Did a lot of Googling and still stuck.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not sure what happened, but when I tried a new project and followed the same steps, everything worked fine.

I guess the takeaway is, if this happens, try re-installing ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Base on my experience, npx command was not recognized as executable command.
I tried changing to npm playwright install and it worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCS5T.png)